# How can I delete an existing Docker Volume (Data Volume) in Amazon Elastic Container Service - ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-volume

I currently have an Nginx Docker image in Amazon ECS. I need to re-issue the SSL certificates via certbot, and I need to delete the old ones. How can I delete the volume? I'm currently going to use new volumes instead of the old ones (appending a "v2" suffix).

Here's part of my task definition (As stated above, I had to rebrand them as v2):

```
"mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "nginx-certbot-v2",
                    "containerPath": "/etc/letsencrypt",
                    "readOnly": false
                },
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "nginx-acme-webroot-v2",
                    "containerPath": "/var/acme-webroot",
                    "readOnly": false
                },
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "nginx-dhparam-v2",
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/dhparam",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
```

Here's the volume definition:

```
"volumes": [
      {
          "name": "nginx-certbot-v2",
          "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
              "scope": "shared",
              "autoprovision": true,
              "driver": "local"
          }
      },
      {
          "name": "nginx-acme-webroot-v2",
          "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
              "scope": "shared",
              "autoprovision": true,
              "driver": "local"
          }
      },
      {
          "name": "nginx-dhparam-v2",
          "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
              "scope": "shared",
              "autoprovision": true,
              "driver": "local"
          }
      }
  ]
```

Are there any possibilities for me to get back the volumes without the "v2"?

Comment: task definations are considered to be immutable you can define the volume with scope: task, so that when you stop the task the volume gets deleted https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html

Comment: let me know if it helps, i'm open for discussion

Comment: @varnit: Thank you! I went back and read it again. I did see `In this example, we specify the scope as task so the volume is deleted after the task stops,` So the true answer is: Specify the dockerVolumeConfiguration's scope as `task` and then stop the task, as it it's going to be deleted. In my case I have it defined as `shared`, therefore they won't be deleted even if the task stops!

Comment: i'm glad it worked i have updated the answer please mark it as solved or upvote it so that it can help other users, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the scope of your docker volume as task instead of shared it will be removed automatically after the task is stopped.

```
"volumes": [
{
    "name": "scratch",
    "dockerVolumeConfiguration" : {
        "scope": "task",
        "autoprovision": true,
        "driver": "local",
        "labels": {
            "scratch": "space"
        }
    }
}
```

]

refer to this link for more information

[ECS docker volume reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html)

Comment: Does the volumes be shared across tasks, if we put the scope to task?

Comment: scope only determines the lifecycle of volume